# simple nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I need to rewrite (convert) this basic htaccess rules to nginx format. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?request=$1
```

And this is my whole site.com nginx config;

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;
server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
root /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html;
access_log /home/user/domains/domain.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/user/domains/domain.com/logs/error.log;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
error_page 404 /404.html;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=$uri;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =403;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-user.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

And this is index.php file contents; if its going to help. it has the clean url functions in it;

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if ( !isset($_GET['debug']) )
    error_reporting(0);

if ( !defined("HQ") || !defined("HQ") )
{
    echo "No sneaky!";
    exit;
}

define( "SYSTEM", HQ . "system/" );
define( "SYSTEM_URL", HQ_URL . "system/" );
define( "FRONTEND", "true" );

// Required files
require_once SYSTEM . "assistants/utf8.php";
require_once SYSTEM . "assistants/config.inc.php";
require_once SYSTEM . "assistants/clerk.php";
require_once "display_functions.php";

// Initialize
$clerk= new Clerk();
$clerk->dbConnect();
$clerk->loadSettings();

// Load plugins
loadPlugins();

// Include all modules
$defaultModules= array( "global", "design", "pages" );
$modules= scanFolder( SYSTEM . "modules", 1 );

foreach ( $defaultModules as $key )
{
    $viewFile= SYSTEM . "modules/" . $key . "/view.php";
    if ( file_exists( $viewFile ) )
    {
        include_once $viewFile;
    }
}

foreach ( $modules as $key => $val )
{
    $viewFile= SYSTEM . "modules/" . $key . "/view.php";
    if ( file_exists( $viewFile ) )
    {
        include_once $viewFile;
    }
}

// Clean URL switching, if requested
// for debugging purposes
if ( isset( $_GET['clean_urls'] ) )
{
    if ( $_GET['clean_urls'] == 0 )
    {
        $clerk->updateSetting( "clean_urls", array( 0 ) );
    }
    elseif ( $_GET['clean_urls'] == 1 )
    {
        $clerk->updateSetting( "clean_urls", array( 1 ) );
    }
}

// URI Router
if ( $clerk->getSetting( "clean_urls", 1 ) == 1 && empty( $_GET['request'] ) == false )
{
    $_GET['request']= utf8_strtolower( $_GET['request'] );

    $uri_routes= call_anchor( "uri_router", array() );

    foreach ( $uri_routes as $pattern => $result )
    {
        if ( preg_match( "#$pattern#", $_GET['request'] ) )
        {   
            $remainder= preg_replace( "#$pattern#", "", $_GET['request'], 1 );

            if ( !empty( $remainder ) ) continue;

            $match= preg_replace( "#$pattern#", $result, $_GET['request'], 1 );
            parse_str( $match, $map );
        }
    }

    $_GET= $map;
}

foreach ( $modules as $key => $val )
{
    $module= getRemappedVar( $key );

    if ( in_array( $key, $defaultModules ) )
    {
        if ( $module == getRemappedVar("pages") && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) )
        {   
            $pageDetails= pageInfo( $_GET[getRemappedVar("pages")] );
            $pageType= $pageDetails['content_type'];

            $layout= $pageType;
            $activeModule= $pageType;
        }

        continue;
    }

    if ( array_key_exists( $module, $_GET ) )
    {
        $layout= $key;
        $activeModule= $key;

        break;
    }
}

if ( empty( $layout ) || $layout == "pages" ) $layout= "default";

$index_page= pageInfo( $clerk->getSetting( "index_page", 1 ) );
$index_page= $index_page['slug'];

$selectedPage= ( empty( $_GET[getRemappedVar("pages")] ) ) ? $index_page : $_GET[getRemappedVar("pages")];
foreach ( $modules as $key => $val )
{
    $module= getRemappedVar( $key );

    if ( !empty( $_GET[getRemappedVar($key)] ) && $module == getRemappedVar("pages") )
    {
        $selectedPage= $_GET[getRemappedVar($key)];
        break;
    }

    // Not viewing a page (domain.com/?projects=id)
    elseif ( !empty( $_GET[getRemappedVar($key)] ) && $module != getRemappedVar("pages") )
    {
        $selectedPage= getRemappedVar($key);
        break;
    }
}

// Constants
call_anchor( "site_init" );

define( "THEME", $clerk->getSetting( "site_theme", 1 ) );
define( "THEME_URL", HQ_URL . "site/themes/" . THEME . "/" );
define( "LAYOUT", "layout_" . $layout . ".php" );
define( "ACTIVE_MODULE", $activeModule );
define( "PAGE", $selectedPage );

// Check if layout exists.
if ( file_exists( HQ . "site/themes/" . THEME . "/" . LAYOUT ) == false )
{
    echo "Oops! Looks like your theme is missing the layout file, <em>" . LAYOUT . "</em>.<br /><br />Create this file and upload it to the root of your theme's folder. Don't forget to fill it with template tags and your custom HTML!";

    exit;
}

call_anchor( "site_begin" );

require_once "themes/" . THEME . "/" . LAYOUT;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use try_files

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike but it didnt work. It didnt give any error but its not working. For example with out clean urls the url is like that; http://www.domain.com/?page=works after i enable clean urls it makes url like this http://www.domain.com/works but it doesnt load the page. Any idea?

Comment: What i did and achieved something. I changed the code like that;

`location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri&$args;
}`

And this is now works but its not working properly. Now all the links domain.com/projects, domain.com/blog and domain.com/about points to domain.com/?page=projects

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, you should use `try_files`, though it needs to be rewritten a bit differently:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=$uri;
}
```

Comment: No Michael its not working. All the links opens the same homepage.

Comment: Did you reload nginx?

Comment: Yes i reloaded NGINX.

Comment: Btw, this is the link format without clean urls; http://www.domain.com/?page=Work  and http://www.domain.com/?page=Work&id=workkk

Comment: I have also updated my question. I have added my whole site.com nginx conf.

Comment: I have updated again with index.php content.